# Disambiguate the [wordle] tag: does it refer to Feinberg's word cloud generator or to Wardle's five-letter-word game?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

[Questions tagged [wordle] pre-dating October 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordle%5D+created%3A..2021-10+is%3aq) all relate to the [word cloud generator](http://web.archive.org/web/20201206102909/http://www.wordle.net/) created by [Jonathan Feinberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143938/jonathan-feinberg).

On the other hand, [questions tagged [wordle] created *after* October 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordle%5D+created%3A2021-10..+is%3aq) all relate to the [five-letter-word game created by Josh Wardle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html), which has captured the attention of many software developers.

[According to Mr Feinberg](https://mrfeinberg.com/):

> Wordle is currently dead; it depends on a technology that's no longer supported in any browser. I have hopes to bring it back to life.

So…which project should get the [wordle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordle) tag?

Comment: "Which project should get the [wordle] tag?" Neither. When will we learn?

Comment: This isn't really something we should have learned. The real problem here is re-using names, which is not the fault of our tag system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They all need a more specific tag name.

The original 5 [wordle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordle) questions should get retagged as [wordle-word-cloud-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordle-word-cloud-generator), and then the [wordle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordle) tag should get renamed to [wordle-game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordle-game). (This did previously say to retag all questions, but [Henry Ecker's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416766/disambiguate-the-wordle-tag-does-it-refer-to-feinbergs-word-cloud-generator#comment900824_416767) is more inline with my intent. I wasn't looking to wipe out the existing wiki info now that it's there.)

Since someone has already changed the tag description to be about the game instead of the original project the tag was for, and because this is how most people will be using the tag, [wordle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordle) should probably be made a synonym for [wordle-game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordle-game). (I think this should be done pre-emptively, rather than waiting for someone to recreate it.)

Comment: Since there are only ~5 wordle word cloud generator questions, it might be easier to retag those few, and then rename [tag:wordle] to [tag:wordle-game]. That'll keep the tag wiki info and limit the amount noise the retagging creates.

Comment: Looks like the former has been created as [tag:wordle-word-cloud].

Comment: Yeah, I somewhat arbitrarily went with [[tag:wordle-word-cloud]] because it was shorter and easier to read without losing any of the uniqueness. It's easy to rename if others disagree with that choice.